# disable gcov in gcc build

Tags: gcc, build-process, gcov

Anyone know how, when making GCC, to tell it not to build gcov? It's giving me lots of errors for my target (powerpc-wrs-vxworks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this line in gcc/Makefile.in:

```
LANGUAGES = c gcov$(exeext) gcov-dump$(exeext) $(CONFIG_LANGUAGES)
```

Try removing the gcov parts and rerun configure.